# Value for HttpClient timeout on a Spring Gateway with resilience4j circuit breaker and time limiter

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty, resilience4j

Should HTTPClient response-timeout be set separately for slow-running calls and separately fast-running calls? Or should it be one timeout value set for all requests?

The application is an Spring Cloud Gateway application which is using CircuitBreaker and TimeLimiter from Resilience4j.

HTTPClient is used to "redirect" requests which are coming to Gateway. They are redirect to specific endpoints. If endpoint response too slowly, the time limiter will stop waiting for response.

The question is what happens with HTTPClient when it is still waiting for a response, because it has a long value of timeout set, however the request has been failed by timelimiter.
Is HTTPClient still waiting? Can be some problem with resource availability?
Or should HTTPClient timeout be configured for each route(endpoint) separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can set cancelRunningFuture on TimeLimiterConfig. It will close the connection properly that belong to HttpClient.